# PHP read file as an array of bytes

Tags: php, binary

I have a file written using `JAVA` program which has an array of integers written as binary I made an for loop over this array and write it using this method

```
public static void writeInt(OutputStream out, int v) throws IOException {
    out.write((v >>> 24) & 0xFF);
    out.write((v >>> 16) & 0xFF);
    out.write((v >>> 8) & 0xFF);
    out.write((v >>> 0) & 0xFF);
}
```

I'm ask about how to read this file in `PHP`.

Comment: look at [unpack](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php)

Comment: @Orangepill I'm new in php and it is hard to dial with manual alone can you help me in a piece of code assume we start reading file with this code `$filename = "myFile.sav";
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe the code you are looking for is:

```
$byteArray = unpack("N*",file_get_contents($filename));
```

**UPDATE:** Working code supplied by OP

```
$filename = "myFile.sav"; 
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb"); 
$fsize = filesize($filename); 
$contents = fread($handle, $fsize); 
$byteArray = unpack("N*",$contents); 
print_r($byteArray); 
for($n = 0; $n < 16; $n++)
{ 
    echo $byteArray [$n].'<br/>'; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Thanks Thanks Orangepill this is what i'm looking for.
the code i'm use :
`$filename = "myFile.sav";
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
$fsize = filesize($filename);
$contents = fread($handle, $fsize);
$byteArray = unpack("N*",$contents);

print_r($byteArray);

for($n = 1; $n <= 16; $n++){
 echo $byteArray [$n].'<br/>';
}`

Comment: I could not get this to work. The example code fails at the unpack. Might be because of the file I'm attempting to read?

Comment: shouldn't it also be a good idead to call `fclose` on the file resource in the working example?

Comment: I found that this results in an array of 32-bit integers, so I'm not sure if the name `$byteArray` is appropriate. To get 8-bit integers, I had to use `C*` instead of `N*`

Answer (score 5):

You should read the file as a string and then use unpack to parse it. In this case you have stored a 32-bit integer in big endian byte order, so use:

```
$out = unpack("N", $in);
```

The format codes are documented here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php

Comment: Thanks Joni but when in execute this code i get an array with one element only the solution below from  Orangepill is so wonderfull and get all element in my file i'm use this code:
`
$filename = "myFile.sav";
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
$fsize = filesize($filename);
$contents = fread($handle, $fsize);

$out = unpack("N", $contents);
print_r($out);
`
this code return one element only

Comment: If your file has packed ints all the way to the end and not just one you can use the asterix `*` formatting code to get them all. Or you can add a number to indicate how many ints should be read. This is all documented on the linked page.