# Byte arithmetic and manipulation of PHP string

Tags: php, byte

If I've read a binary file into a variable using `$data = fread('myfile','rb')` how can I work through `$data` a byte at a time. I also want to perform operations on each byte, such as multiplying it by a number and calculating the modulo with respect to another number.

I can reference the variable as an array using `$data[$i]`, but am I getting bytes with this or possibly multi-byte characters? Also when I do this, I can't then perform calculations on the results, such as `$data[$i]*4`, which is always zero.

I need work through very large files so the solution needs to be quick.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP read file as an array of bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963110/php-read-file-as-an-array-of-bytes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can reference the variable as an array using $data[$i], but am I getting bytes with this or possibly multi-byte characters?

You'll get bytes. PHP strings are single-byte.

> Also when I do this, I can't then perform calculations on the results, such as $data[$i]*4, which is always zero.

Convert a character to a number with `ord`, make your calculations and, if needed, convert back with `chr`. Alternatively, convert the whole buffer with `unpack('c*', $buf)`, which gives you a numeric array.

Comment: What sort of overhead is there with ord and unpack? I'd seen those functions but dismissed them as I assumed they'd be very slow.

Comment: I've done some very rough benchmarking which has shown that neither ord nor unpack are quick (both about a second per meg on my development machine). Unpack is ridiculously expensive in terms of memory, using about 200 times the memory of the data which is unpacked. As the data has been read into a variable, it exists as bytes in memory, is there no lower level method to access it directly?

Comment: @Dom: `ord` is a very simple function and is as fast as it gets. If you want your loop to be even faster, you probably need a compiled language, like C.

Comment: ord is just way to slow for the amount of data I'm trying to process. As a string must have a binary representation within PHP, I was hoping to be able to access and manipulate that a byte at a time. Functions such as mhash clearly must work on the data in a binary representation and seem to be three orders of magnitude faster per byte than ord.