# How do I parse int32 from array-bytes to php int?

Tags: php

Is there a clever way to convert bytes in array into PHP-int.

```
//data holding three int32's
$data = array(0,53,100,200,0,0,0,0,10,20,30,40);
$myInt1 = cleverWay($data,0,'big-endian'); //0 = startpoint to parse

//myInt1 should now contain 0 + 53 * 2^8 + 100 * 2^16 + 200 * 2^24
//(there's a glitch here since int32 probably is signed and
//comment above uint32.
```

Comment: What's the expected output? I'm a bit confused about the 12 values and "three int32" comment.

Comment: Are you asking to sum the ints in the array to one int?

Comment: Are you learning or copy-pasting code from somewhere ... ?

Comment: Sorry guys, hope it's clearer now. Php unpack(). Is that the way to go here?

Comment: `(0 << 24) + (53 << 16) + (100 << 8) + 200`, basically.

Comment: The thing is, I'm having binary data in string, as bytes. It's filled with int32's at different positions. I need to get them into regular php variables. Easily. I can do it. But I guess there are C-ways to do it that i'm unaware of.

Comment: for reading unit32 from strings take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17963326/5378743