# Reading Encoded File in PHP

Tags: php, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have a text file that displays as below when I open it in Sublime Text:

[image]

But when I `fread` the file and echo each line in php, I get garbled characters like this:

[image]

I read [Joel's post on encoding](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) and understood the basics of encoding. Also, When I do `mb_detect_encoding`, it detects the string as UTF-8. Now, I do not understand what I have to do with this information of what encoding the string is in in order to display it, or convert it, to readable characters like in the first picture.

And why is it displaying garbled characters when it is already in UTF-8? Is php using different encoding type to read the file? Does php string have to be in UTF-8 or ASCII, or does it not matter as long as I specify what it is?

I would really appreciate if someone can help me understanding the idea! Thanks.

EDIT:

Pedro Lobito and Peter's suggestions worked.

```
$file = file_get_contents($bl_file);
$content = unpack("H*", $file);
```

But if someone could explain why I have to do this way, that'd still help me understanding it!

Comment: If you echo it on the shell, is it utf-8 too? Normally in Windows it is not.

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963110/php-read-file-as-an-array-of-bytes

Comment: why don't you use `file_get_contents()` ? this will ensure you'll get the file content as a text string.

Comment: @PedroLobito it will ensure nothing. It will just get raw file content into a buffer, that's all. PHP manual: >This function is binary-safe.

Comment: You say *"I have a text file"*. What makes you think it is a text file? Can you read it using some editor (MS Word, f.e.)?

Comment: Sublime text opens binary files automatically in a HEX mode representation.

Comment: @strangeqargo `file_get_contents()` **"This function is similar to file(), except that file_get_contents() returns the file in a string"** - http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But if someone could explain why I have to do this way, that'd still help me understanding it!

Because it's a binary file. Sublime shows you  hex human-readable representation of raw binary values.

When you do file_get_contents, you read a file into a string of '0101010', raw bits and bytes.

When you do unpack (H* /* H is for HEX */, $file ), you're telling PHP, you want to see your binary data as a human-readable hex encoded representation of your byte-stream. (You can tell it's a hex when you see letters A-F)

HEX encoding is far more readable than binary, that's why Sublime uses it. Also, I once saw a man who can code in raw binary. I was scared.

When you echo them, you're just streaming raw binary values to console, they have no special meaning, so console(or browser) shows them as a control characters and other garbage, which has now meaning for a human eye.

So, if you open this file with another text editor, it will:

a) show garbage (mcedit)

b) show garbage and tell you that it's a binary file (vim, gedit)

Sublime tricked you into thinking it's a text file by being too friendly.

If you'll echo binary files to your command prompt / shell it can kill your data. Never do this. Because shell can interpret raw binary data as  a command and run it.

If you'll echo some binary file having something like this inside:

`rm -rf ~/[bytecode_For_NewLine_Here]`,

you can delete your home folder contents in linux