# PHP: unpack 32 bit integers from binary stream of data

Tags: php, binary

I have a 1024 bit long binary stream of data which I'd like to convert to an array of 32-bit integers (e.i. 32 numbers).
From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963110/php-read-file-as-an-array-of-bytes) I used this code:

```
$filename = "myFile.sav"; 
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb"); 
$fsize = filesize($filename); 
$contents = fread($handle, $fsize); 
$byteArray = unpack("N*",$contents); 
print_r($byteArray);
```

And even though it formats itself as "N", var_dump then prints out an array of 256 8-bit long integers. (I want 32 32-bit long numbers). What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: its not actually 256 8-bit numbers, but 256 gibberish values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your file contains the binary representation of your integers. Given any `string` representation of bits, the `bindec` function will convert them properly to `integer`:

```
$content = "1000110010110110100100101011000100100000101011010101101110101101011101110011001110010010111101001011111000111000101110011110011100110110000111001110000011001101011100111011110000001110111100100110110001000111111001010101100011100101010111000011010101010010001101101100011001101110001001000101110111011001001101111000110101010001101010000101110000100010000110110111000110001110000010000111001100100111110011000101000110100011111100100011110100101010101101011011101100111000101011110111111010001110000011101001011101111010101010011010011010011101100011111111000110000110000000000101110110010100010011010001110101101100110110001011010010010000011000111101110000100100001101100010101011000110010110110111100111010010101110000101011101010010101110100111100111110011000100001010111110010001010100001010001011101101110010011001010000101011110101100001100001111011101010100001001101100100110001101000000110111000111001100001000110000011011100000100011100100110101101000101111011110001100110010001111111010101110111111010110010111001";

$parts = str_split($content, 32);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($parts); ++$i) {
    $parts[$i] = bindec($parts[$i]);
}

print_r($parts);
```